# How does set_index and groupby work together?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I came across this line of code and was wondering the mechanics of it.

```
df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)['CENSUS2010POP']
    .agg({'avg': np.average, 'sum': np.sum}))
                    avg     sum
STNAME      
Alabama     71339.343284    4779736
Alaska  24490.724138    710231
Arizona     426134.466667   6392017
Arkansas    38878.906667    2915918
California  642309.586207   37253956
Colorado    78581.187500    5029196
```

Does it group with respect to state names first following which it aggregates on Census? If that's the case then why is the groupby parameter Census

Comment: the groupby parameter is `level=0`, not `Census`, `set_index` first set the `STNAME` as the index of the `df`, then `groupby` the `index`, then `agg` on `Census`

Comment: Unnecessary, it is better to use `df.groupby('STNAME')` directly.

Comment: This is probably older pandas code, in pandas 0.19 or so, an update of the pandas library allows you for you to group on either column labels and/or index names.  Hence, @coldspeed is correct, you can group on 'STNAME' directly with update pandas library.